# undefined index from form post (untypical)

Tags: php, html, post

Here is the page with a table, which contains info rows that generates for every row from request.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    $mysqli=connect();
    $result=$mysqli->query("request is here");
    while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<form action='script.php' method='post'>";
        if ($rows['admin']>$_SESSION['admin']||$_SESSION['admin']<6||$rows['online']==1)
            $levelinput='<td><input type="text" class="input-sm 
            form-control" value="'.$rows['admin'].'" disabled></td>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-
            simple btn-sm" value="Change" disabled></td>';
        else $levelinput='<td><input type="number" class="input-sm 
        form-control" name="level" value="'.$rows['admin'].'"></td> ----- LEVEL IS HERE
        <td class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-round 
        btn-simple btn-sm btn-warning" value="Change"></td>';
    if ($rows['ucp_online']>time()-60*5) $name=$rows['login']." <span 
    class='label label-success'>ONLINE</span>";
    else $name=$rows['login'];
    echo '
          <tr>
             <td>'.$rows['id'].'</td>
             <td><a href="/admin/user.php?id='.$rows['id'].'" class="btn 
             btn-simple btn-sm">'.$name.'</a></td>
             '.$levelinput.'
          </tr>
          <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="'.$rows['id'].'">
    </form>';
    }
    $mysqli->close();
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Form moves us to `script.php`, which takes only `$_POST['admin']` index and don't takes `$_POST['level']` index. And of course, at the page `level` value displays correctly.

Comment: In your code, if condition , input tag does not have any name. That might be the reason.

Comment: @T.Shah, if you are talking about "Change" tag, it don't need any name, it just triggers the form action.

Comment: Then could that be, because of level input type is number?

Comment: @T.Shah, tried text, no changes

Comment: No more ideas... Inspect element in browser, if that gives any clues..

Comment: @T.Shah, only `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on script page

Comment: I tried the code and I get level as well as admin. So investigate on error.

Comment: @T.Shah, wow, what the hell